# Stm32F4 Flash Memory Start Address

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I want to start flash on `0x8009000`address instead of `0x8000000` when I reset the stm32.
I changed FLASH address in ld table and VECT_TAB_OFFSET but it didn't work.

I need to start 0x8009000 address with user code because if I get firmware update message I need to jump bootloader source code. How can I do that ?

Comment: 0x9000 is 54kB.  This probably isn't a sector boundary so you will end up erasing more that you intended when you try to program here.  Also you need to reduce the LENGTH of FLASH by the same amount that you increase ORIGIN.  Other than that this should work unless you have made some other mistake not shown.

Comment: I know, I set the size in real code. But my main question is, Can I change after reset address to another address instead of 0x8000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STM32F4 will start program execution from 0x0800000. That could not be changed
(You could use the BOOT pins to start from RAM or system memory instead).

If you want to use a custom bootloader, the best way is to always start the bootloader (place it at address 0x08000000) and let it jump to you application if no reprogramming is needed.